# When ever I run this music script it works except for changing the GUI text to the current song name

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local mouse = player:GetMouse()

local mutebutton = script.Parent

local track = game.StarterGui.MusicPlayer.Track

local b = game.StarterGui.MusicPlayer.Playlist:GetChildren()

local c = math.random(1, #b)

local d = b[c]

while true do
    wait()
    d:Play()
    

    local connection = mutebutton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        if d.IsPaused then
            d:Resume()
            mutebutton.Text = "Pause"
        else
            d:Pause()
            mutebutton.Text = "Resume"
        end
    end)

    d.Ended:Wait() 
    connection:Disconnect() 
    
    d:GetPropertyChangedSignal("SoundId"):Connect(function()
        track.Text = d.Name
    end)
    
end
```

Everything works until the Get Property Changed Signal event. Whenever I load into the game the box that should have the song name will instead not do anything and keep it as an empty box. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a single mute button (not one for each song), so why are you putting the pausing functionality inside a while loop?

You're not changing the sound id anywhere, is there more code that you're not showing?

You have a variable "local d" but this is only ever calculated outside of the loop so it will just repeat the same song over.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local mouse = player:GetMouse()

local mutebutton = script.Parent

local track = game.StarterGui.MusicPlayer.Track

local b = game.StarterGui.MusicPlayer.Playlist:GetChildren()

local c = math.random(1, #b)

local song -- definite it originally here as nil so we can access it outside of the loop

mutebutton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
   if song.IsPaused then
       song:Resume()
       mutebutton.Text = "Pause"
   else
       song:Pause()
       mutebutton.Text = "Resume"
   end
end)

while true do
    
    song = b[math.random(1, #b)]
    track.Text = song.Name
    song:Play()

    song.Ended:Wait() 

    task.wait()
end
```

This might work, but I can't see your Explorer